# calculating Pi with Monte Carlo Simulation Multithreaded

Tags: c, multithreading

So, I'm currently working on a Monte Carlo Simulation in order to calculate Pi. I have currently 5 different scenarios: 500, 20000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000 points to calculate Pi, my problem is that I have to multithread the algorithm ( 2, 4, 6 and 8 threads for each number of points ) but I've been searching about multithreading and couldn't understand what do I have to do in order to achieve my goal.
Hoping someone could explain me or show me how to actually do the multithreading bit of the algorithm.

Code looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main () 
{

 int circ, total, i;
 double a, x, y, pi;

 a = 0;
 i = 0;

 total = 500;
 circ = 0;
 for ( i = 0; i<total; i++ ) {
  x = (double)rand ()/ RAND_MAX;
  y = (double)rand ()/ RAND_MAX;
  a = x*x + y*y
  if (a<=1) circ ++;
  }
 pi = (double)circ/total * 4;
 printf ("For %d points, pi is %g \n", total, pi);

 total = 20000;
 circ = 0;
 for ( i = 0; i<total; i++ ) {
  x = (double)rand ()/ RAND_MAX;
  y = (double)rand ()/ RAND_MAX;
  a = x*x + y*y
  if (a<=1) circ ++;
  }
 pi = (double)circ/total * 4;
 printf ("For %d points, pi is %g \n", total, pi);


 total = 100000;
 circ = 0;
 for ( i = 0; i<total; i++ ) {
  x = (double)rand ()/ RAND_MAX;
  y = (double)rand ()/ RAND_MAX;
  a = x*x + y*y
  if (a<=1) circ ++;
  }
 pi = (double)circ/total * 4;
 printf ("For %d points, pi is %g \n", total, pi);


 total = 1000000;
 circ = 0;
 for ( i = 0; i<total; i++ ) {
  x = (double)rand ()/ RAND_MAX;
  y = (double)rand ()/ RAND_MAX;
  a = x*x + y*y
  if (a<=1) circ ++;
  }
 pi = (double)circ/total * 4;
 printf ("For %d points, pi is %g \n", total, pi);

 total = 10000000;
 circ = 0;
 for ( i = 0; i<total; i++ ) {
  x = (double)rand ()/ RAND_MAX;
  y = (double)rand ()/ RAND_MAX;
  a = x*x + y*y
  if (a<=1) circ ++;
  }
 pi = (double)circ/total * 4;
 printf ("For %d points, pi is %g \n", total, pi);
```

Thank you very much for your patience and have a good day :)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to follow a C multithreading tutorial step by step?

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you have to consider when writing a multithreaded version of your program or algorithym is

1. You must first of all identify parts of your application that would 
   enjoy multithreading or that need to run parallel. Which is the for 
   loop sections of your code
2. The sections or branches of your code you wish to parallelize must be
    independent of each other, to avoid things like race condition. And 
    by  what am seeing from your code, the dependency between the 
    potential branch of code to enjoy multithreading is in this 
    condition.

   `a = x * x + y * y;
   if ( a <= 1 ) circ++;`

   if you come up with a multithreaded version of this your code, you will have to deal with things like race condition because all threads will want to concurrently write to the `a` shared memory. Even if you try to make each threads exclusively write to the shared memory, you might end up having another issue which might be the serial version of you code been much more faster than the parallel version, the cause of this might be a thread which have to loop for a very long time holding a lock which prevents other threads from accessing the `a` shared memory. Trying to use  lockless mechanisms ( for example atomics ) will also lead to issues such as memory ordering

**what you should do**

What you should do now is to redesign your code in a way were the loops will have no dependency in any way or if you are ready to face the perils of multithreading without redesigning your code you can take a look at this book, it has a section for learning pthreads and omp. It's a nice book but most examples won't compile depends on which c standard you are compiling with

`Darryl Gove - Multicore Application Programming for Windows, Linux, and Oracle Solaris - 2010`